# viewpager as listview header

Tags: listview, header, android-viewpager

i have one list view. i can add any view to it as header. but when i try to add viewpager of images  my app will crash.

my viewpager size is set too.

**header_view.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     **strong text**android:layout_height="150dp"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

viewpage_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

viewpageradapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 Context c;
 String images[];
 LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context c, String[] imagePaths) {
        this.images = imagePaths;
        this.c = c;

    }
    @Override    public int getCount() {
        return this.images.length;
    }
    @Override    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == (object);
    }

    @Override    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpage_item, container,
                false);
        ImageView image;
        image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.image);

       try {
           Picasso.with(c).
                   load(images[position])
                   .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                   .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                   .into(image);
       }
       catch ( Exception Ex)
       {           Toast.makeText(c, "catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
        container.addView(itemview);
        return itemview;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
         ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

and in list view fragment i have this code

listfragment.java

public class listfragment extends ListFragment implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

```
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private  String[] images= {
        "url1","url2"};
Context contextSl = this.getActivity();
private   listadapter newadp;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View headerView;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity());

    headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, null, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(contextSl, images);
    newadp=new listadapter(getActivity(),model);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().addHeaderView(headerView);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams headerViewParams = new 
    AbsListView.LayoutParams(Const.width, 400);
    headerView.setLayoutParams(headerViewParams);
    setListAdapter(newadp);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener( this);
    getListView().setDivider(null);
    getListView().setDividerHeight(16);

}
```

////////////////////